# Using ngRoute and getting 404 Error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

All, I was reading [The tutorial of $route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).
and try to get the example work against my IIS. When I click the link in the page. The address of chrome will be changed like below.

[image]

And when I tried to reload the page by hitting the `enter` key in the address bar. I supposed it will reload page content for the `Moby`. But I got a error `404`. I don't know if this is the best practice for ngRoute. Why I got 404 error.

[image]

I didn't want to demo it in the jsfiddle or plunker . because I thought it will be difference from deploying it in the IIS. So I post the code below.  Thanks.

**TestRoute.html**

```
<html ng-app="ngRouteExample">
<head>
    <title>Angualar js test</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var routeApp=angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute']);

        routeApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
             $scope.$route = $route;
             $scope.$location = $location;
             $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
         }).controller('BookController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
             $scope.name = "BookController";
             $scope.params = $routeParams;
         }).controller('ChapterController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
             $scope.name = "ChapterController";
             $scope.params = $routeParams;
         });

        routeApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider
           .when('/Book/:bookId', {
            templateUrl: 'book.html',
            controller: 'BookController',
            resolve: {
              // I will cause a 1 second delay
              delay: function($q, $timeout) {
                var delay = $q.defer();
                $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                return delay.promise;
              }
            }
          })
          .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
            templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
            controller: 'ChapterController'
          });

          // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });

    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="book.html">
        controller: {{name}}<br />
        Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="chapter.html">
        controller: {{name}}<br />
        Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
        Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      Choose:
      <a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
      <a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
      <a href="Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
      <a href="Book/Gatsby/ch/4?key=value">Gatsby: Ch4</a> |
      <a href="Book/Scarlet">Scarlet Letter</a><br/>

      <div ng-view></div>

      <hr />

      <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
      <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
      <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
      <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
      <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>
    </div>
<body>
```

Comment: is that mvc project ?

Comment: no, just plain html pages.

Comment: so you need to set up redirect to your home page (index.html) for all request in your IIS, because angular route is not working until the scripts on your home page start executing.

Answer (score 4):

**If you do not require html5mode**

You can remove `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Your link would change to `http://localhost:86/#/Book/Moby`, but the server would be able to handle the address without any additional changes.

**On the other hand**

If you absolutely have to remove the `#` then you will need to setup server side redirect specific to your stack so the server knows where to find the page.

[Link rewrite exampled](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

If you go down the `html5mode(true)` you should also add a check before you initialize html5mode for browsers where it is currently not supported.  Then update the links in your application appropriately based on html5mode being set.

Answer (score 2):

The problem come from your server, when you refresh you send a request for /book/moby and it doesn't know how to answer it. You need to setup a redirect.